# How to change UIView size in Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

In Interface Builder when I look at the size inspector for the view, it's showing 320x416 and it's grayed out so I can't change it. How can this be made editable?

Answer (score 15):

Change the `UIView`'s "Size" in the "Simulated Metrics" area in the inspector to "Freeform". Then you can change the `Width` and `Height` in "View" area in the inspector.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: nicely explained keep it up :-)

Comment: FYI for Xcode 8 it's now in the ViewController's setting.

Answer (score 4):

if you have any of the metrics (status bar, top navigation bar, etc) it won't let you resize the view.

Comment: In some cases when IB won't let you set view attributes, you can wire an IBOutlet in the controller and have code there manipulate the view.